# Loop through cursor, doing INSERTS during each iteration

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

I have a cursor `c_email` that contains a query of email addresses. I need to loop through it, doing insert statements each iteration.

How do you loop through a cursor in powerbuilder, until the cursor is at the end

so far I have the follow:

```
DECLARE c_email CURSOR FOR
 SELECT email_id
     ...

OPEN c_email;
CLOSE c_email;
```

Comment: Don't use a cursor to insert in a loop - especially if you already have a query that gets all the values. It's terribly inefficient. Use an `INSERT ... SELECT` instead. That will be ***a lot*** faster and will definitely scale better.

Comment: that doesn't really help me though?

Comment: You do know how to write an `INSERT .. SELECT` query? Then use that instead of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OPEN c_email;
DO WHILE TRUE
FETCH c_email INTO :bind_variable;
if sqlca.sqlcode<>0 then exit 
End If
//......insert statement..
LOOP
CLOSE c_email ;
```

Or

Sybase supports selecting values from a table and inserting into the another table.

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( <column list> )
SELECT ( <column list> ) FROM table2 ; --> this is the SELECT from the CURSOR
```

Comment: To anyone looking at this answer: doing inserts in a loop if the results are obtained from a SELECT query is very bad coding style. It is inefficient, wastes resources and will not scale (the answer is correct regarding the question - the problem is the question is already wrong)

Comment: Well... What if you want to do some enrichment to the values fetched using some procedures and then Insert into a table?? the question was treated as "How to loop a cursor in Sybase Powerbuilder" by me, and here's the answer. And by the way I updated it with `INSERT INTO...SELECT` way too.

Comment: As I said: your answer is correct as far as the question is concerned (thanks for adding the insert solution). The question itself is wrong (if Steve wants to do some enrichments he should have said so). Btw: not only Sybase supports that syntax. That's ANSI SQL and will also work with Oracle (which Steve is using).

Comment: Yes but there's another tag called `powerbuilder`.

Comment: @Annjawn: Not sure what the comment about the PowerBuilder tag means, because a) PowerBuilder handles more databases than Sybase (in fact, at least at one point, Oracle was significantly more used in PB shops than Sybase), and b) PowerBuilder supports `INSERT INTO... SELECT...` (as I thought you were implying in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are people still using CURSORS in 2012?  1985 called - they want their technology back...

This is POWERBUILDER.  There's this crazy thing called a DATAWINDOW.  If you can't figure out how to do a set-based INSERT/SELECT (which is the best approach), then code your query into a datawindow retrieval and loop through it in PowerScript.

```
FOR x = 1 to dw_1.rowcount()
  // ls_variable = dw_1.GetItemString( x, "colName")
  // INSERT into table (ls_variable, blah, blah);
  // Error checking
  // COMMIT or ROLLBACK
NEXT
```

Comment: For the first answer, I'd go with a_horse_with_no_name if possible, but if you need client side "enrichment" or other scripting, the DataWindow is the way to go. Why? Because the cursor route is going to keep locks on all the tables during this whole process; like ahwnn says, this presents scaling problems with resources locked from other users. Bring your data back, release the source table ASAP, massage the data, do your INSERTs as quickly as possible (or at least keep you LUW as short as possible for each INSERT) and let the database get back to being available.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side cursor is not the best solution. It's better to write such a code in a stored procedure.
http://www.zuskin.com/pb_code.htm#Avoid_SQL